# ¿Alguien sabe como puedo ingresar datos de un vector separados por espacio?

Tags: java, array, string, netbeans, bucle-for

Buenos dias tengo un codigo en el cual ingreso un dato al comienzo y con ese dato se le da el tamaño del vector, pero quiero hacerlos separados por un espacio como hago?

ejm seria algo asi: como podemos observar en la segunda linea se ingresan los datos separados por espacio " "; si alguien me ayuda seria genial ¿podria con la funcion .split?

[image: Aqui esta el ejemplo de la entrada que quiero hacer]

```
  import java.io.BufferedReader;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.InputStreamReader;

 public class BerSUBall {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int nBoy = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    int [] skillsBoy = new int [nBoy];
    for (int i = 0; i < skillsBoy.length; i++) {
        skillsBoy[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    }
    int mGirl = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    int [] skillsGirl = new int [mGirl];
    for (int i = 0; i < skillsGirl.length; i++) {
        skillsGirl[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sería primero leer la línea y crear un arreglo de cadenas. Luego iterar la lista y convertir cada cadena a entero y asignarlo al arreglo.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int nBoy = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int [] skillsBoy = new int [nBoy];
        
        String[] numeros = br.readLine().split(" ");
        
        for (int i = 0; i < skillsBoy.length; i++) {
            skillsBoy[i] = Integer.parseInt(numeros[i]);
        }
        
        int mGirl = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int [] skillsGirl = new int [mGirl];

        numeros = br.readLine().split(" ");

        for (int i = 0; i < skillsGirl.length; i++) {
            skillsGirl[i] = Integer.parseInt(numeros[i]);
        }
    }
```

Código usando streams.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        br.readLine(); // descartar la línea con el número de elementos del arreglo

        int[] skillsBoy;

        String[] numeros = br.readLine().split(" "); // crear arreglo con los números

        skillsBoy = Arrays.stream(numeros) // crear stream de cadenas a partir del arreglo numeros
                .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt) // convertir cada cadena en un entero
                .toArray(); // crear un arrreglo de enteros


        br.readLine();
        int[] skillsGirl;
        numeros = br.readLine().split(" ");
        skillsGirl = Arrays.stream(numeros).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();

    }
```

---

**Actualización**

Para ordenar los arreglos puedes usar `Arrays.sort()`:

```
Arrays.sort(skillsBoy);
```

Comment: genial bro otra pregunta como hago para ordenar los vectores de menor a mayor?

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta.

Comment: gracias crack :v